# SQL - Select Statment always returning 10 Rows

Tags: sql, select

Hi I need to return 10 Rows always in a dataset using a Select statement, if the select statement return any number of rows <10 I need to have blank rows added

Please can someone help me with this

Comment: And why to do so?

Comment: Blank rows with how many columns ? A select statement defines the number of columns returned, so you cannot add rows when you do not know how many (or much?) columns your have.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. This would only be achievable with procedural code as the number of rows a query returns is not known until the query has been executed - so you would need one step to run the query and then a second step to get the row count and take the appropriate action in order to return the required number of rows.  But, to echo @JonasMetzler's comments, what's the use case for needing to implement this unusual behaviour?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Have a 10 row help table/recursive cte or similiar. Outer join on row_number. (Will perhaps be somewhat product specific, so I will await the dbms tag until I answer.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77016737/sql-extra-null-lines shows you one way to do this. (Oracle answer, but the idea is the same.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with the Query below?

```
   DECLARE @TEMP TABLE
(
A NVARCHAR(10),
B NVARCHAR(10),
C NVARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @TEMP
/*Replace with your data ⇣⇣⇣*/
VALUES
(N'TESTA-001',N'TESTB-001',N'TESTC-001'),
(N'TESTA-002',N'TESTB-002',N'TESTC-002'),
(N'TESTA-003',N'TESTB-003',N'TESTC-003'),
(N'TESTA-004',N'TESTB-004',N'TESTC-004'),
(N'TESTA-005',N'TESTB-005',N'TESTC-005');

WITH CTE(NO) AS
(
SELECT 1 AS NO
UNION ALL
SELECT NO + 1 NO
FROM CTE
WHERE NO < 10
)
SELECT A,B,C,A.NO
FROM CTE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT A,B,C,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A) AS NO FROM @TEMP 
) B ON A.NO = B.NO
```

Output:

```
A           B           C           NO
TESTA-001   TESTB-001   TESTC-001   1
TESTA-002   TESTB-002   TESTC-002   2
TESTA-003   TESTB-003   TESTC-003   3
TESTA-004   TESTB-004   TESTC-004   4
TESTA-005   TESTB-005   TESTC-005   5
NULL        NULL        NULL        6
NULL        NULL        NULL        7
NULL        NULL        NULL        8
NULL        NULL        NULL        9
NULL        NULL        NULL       10
```

Comment: When input dataset has more than 10 records, then more than 10 records will be returned (for this MSSQL answer)

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with 10 empty rows and the same columns as you expect to get from your statement. (Call it EMPTY for example)

Then declare an INT variable for the number of rows in your statement

```
DECLARE @ROWS
SET @ROWS  = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM STATEMENT)
```

Then select the top 10 rows from your statement and UNION ALL
the top 10-@rows lines of the empty table you created.

```
DECLARE @ROWS INT
SET @ROWS = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STATEMENT)
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM STATEMENT
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN 10-@ROWS <=0 THEN 0 ELSE 10-@ROWS END) * FROM EMPTY
```

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...." (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/23imtUSV)) Or, in other words, let @smarteez read the description of [tag:sql]